# Flex Comparing Class Object to Class

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, class

The question itself may not convey exactly what I mean, so I will quickly jump into the code.

```
var myClass:Class;
```

And I have my Class A defined with myClass storing Class A.

```
myClass = getDefinitionByName("myPackage.A") as Class;
```

Problem is how can I verify if myClass is storing the Class A. The following snippet doesn't work.

```
if(myClass == A){
  Alert.show("equal");
}
```

Why does this comparison fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Comparing by package name:

```
if(getQualifiedClassName(myClass) == getQualifiedClassName(A)){
      Alert.show("equal");
}
```

Comment: Babibu. You are right. Although I realized it was mistake on my part in framing the question. See the issue is suppose I have a class B extends A. Now myClass is having the Class B instead of A. The check above fails but which I want to be true. I'll accept this as answer to the question though.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
if(getQualifiedSuperclassName(ClassB) == getQualifiedClassName(ClassA))
{
      Alert.show("equal");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have classes A and B and `B extends A`, you can use:

```
var type:String = getQualifiedClassName(A);
for each (var object:Object in describeType(B)..extendsClass) {
    if (type == object.@type.toString())
        trace("Class B instead of A");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if(myClass is myPackage.A)
{
   Alert.show("equal");
}
```

Comment: I think that'd only work for an instance variable, don't you think?

Comment: yes, Gio u r right. The comparison would have worked for an instance variable.